# Raspberry pi wireless WiFi

Tags: pi-3, pi-2

So I had an idea and wanted to know if it was possible and how to tackle it. So I was thinking if I had a raspberry pi plugged into my router at home via Ethernet cable, could I create some sort of satellite thing that could make it reach to my school so there are no limitations to the WiFi there and if I would need a second raspberry pi that I take to school to connect to thank you

Comment: How far away is your school?

Comment: What do you mean with: "*some sort of satellite thing that could make it reach to my school*"? Do you want to use a 4G mobile connection, maybe using a modem or a smartphone, and/or do you have connection to the internet on a side?

Comment: Although the question is not very precise, I guess that the "limitations" are in the school WiFi (because they usually are). If that is the case, a "home made" VPN service is what is asked for. Yeah, that can be done, but usually a commercial VPN service is better and allows skipping the RPI's and the home network. BUT, if the school WiFi admin has "limited" the network it is probably because the school has a policy against some uses. They may also have a policy against VPNs, or even limits the use of them.